# An explanation with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I trying to get some data for my JavaFX Application from a couple of tables in database with MySQl.

Here's the query:

```
 select veturattable.id, veturattable.vetura,veturattable.modeli,veturattable.ngjyra,
     veturattable.targa, renttable.pagesa, hargjimettable.shuma 
        from veturattable 
     left join hargjimettable 
        on hargjimettable.veturaid= veturattable.id 
        left join renttable  
     on renttable.veturaid = veturattable.id ;
```

Here are datas from rentable

[image]

And here are datas from hargjimettable

[image]

So what I need is to show me this one:

```
veturaid | pagesa | shuma
1        | 150    | 91
10       | 110    | 40
```

Comment: Are all the columns going to be the same except SHUMA? do you always want the MAX(SHUMA) ?

Comment: You can see from picture 1 two rows with id 1 (one has shuma=30 and one has shuma=1) , so i want just one row with id 1 and shuma has to be (30 + 1). If you can understand me

Comment: You should post the create tables statements and some example data

Comment: Rahul posted the answer and thats what i wanted.

Comment: Well, if you say so...

Comment: Have a look at `group by` and `sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to do two subqueries pre-aggregating the sum amounts per respective ID.  Then join each individually back to the main.  If you don't, you are getting a Cartesian product.  For every record in the hargjimettable table for a given ID, it is joined to the renttable for each amount there.  So, if you have 2 records in first table and 3 records in the second, you are getting a multiple of 6.

By pre-querying each grouping by the one ID key respectively, you will only have at most, one record for each possible summation.  So grab that record if it exists.  The left-join prevents some IDs from not showing up.  Using coalesce() prevents nulls from showing.

```
select 
      v.id, 
      v.vetura,
      v.modeli,
      v.ngjyra,
      v.targa, 
      COALESCE( RSum.SumPagesa, 0 ) as AllPagesa, 
      COALESCE( HSum.SumShuma, 0 ) as AllShuma
   from 
      veturattable v
         left join 
         ( select 
                 h.veturaid,
                 SUM( h.shuma ) as SumShuma
              from 
                 hargjimettable h
              group by
                 h.veturaid ) HSum
           ON v.id = HSum.veturaid
        left join 
        ( select
                r.veturaid,
                SUM( r.pagesa ) as SumPagesa
             from
                renttable r
             group by
                r.veturaid ) RSum
           ON v.id = RSum.veturaid
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want the `MAX()` and `SUM()` along the `GROUP BY` like

```
 select max(veturattable.id) as id, max(veturattable.vetura) as vetura,
max(veturattable.modeli) as modeli,
max(veturattable.ngjyra) as ngjyra,
     max(veturattable.targa) as targa, 
max(renttable.pagesa) as pagesa, 
sum(hargjimettable.shuma) as shuma 
        from veturattable 
     left join hargjimettable 
        on hargjimettable.veturaid= veturattable.id 
        left join renttable  
     on renttable.veturaid = veturattable.id 
group by veturattable.id;
```

Comment: Thank you this work just as i want to . But i also tried to make SUM() to renttable.pagesa and it gives me 100 intstead of 50 and in the other id 200 instead of 100 (it doubles the sum). How to make that work

Comment: also i forgot to tell you that in the first row its all good , but in the second row it doubles the shuma dont know why

Comment: @ErtanHasani, post some sample data from both table else I have no idea what you are talking about actually

Comment: Select max thing group by thing. That's fun.

Comment: @Rahul take a look at the very first post i edited by adding data from database and how it should looks like